# Permission denied Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

s Hi everyone! Tell me someone.
Where can i get my password to log in to my Ubuntu Server on Virtualbox?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBX3F.png

Thanks!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is *localhost*, and **not** your VM most likely. Your VM would have a different IP - depending on the network setup.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: My problem was solved. Thanks for your attention!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password is the same as the one you log into your VM server when starting it. The Ip address is wrong tho. If your VM is on VirtualBox go to settings->Network->Change the **attached to**: Bridged adapter . That should fix it. Then when running ifconfig you should see different ip address. try connecting to that one .

Comment: Wоw, man, thanks a lot! I thought it something wrong with my sshd_config. I appreciate your help.